# How to have video be ready to play in swift

Tags: ios, swift, video, swift2, playback

The following code has a video being played. But the video starts immediately when the view controller is launch. When the view controller is launch I would like the user to hit the play button for the video to play. Now the video plays as soon as the view controller is launched.

```
 let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("x", ofType:"mp4")
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)
    self.moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
    if let player = self.moviePlayer {
        player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 55, y: 75, width: self.view.frame.size.width/2, height: self.view.frame.size.height / 5)
        player.view.sizeToFit()
        player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingMode.AspectFit
        player.fullscreen = false
        player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Default
        player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
        player.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatMode.One
        player.play()
        self.view.addSubview(player.view)
```

Comment: Create your UIButton. Add a target (`myButton.addTarget`). Move `player.play()` from where you currently have it to inside this target function.

Comment: could you tell me exactly what i need to put in the ibaction function?